# Name this matrix

Tags: matrices, terminology

\begin{bmatrix}
1&a_1&a_1^2&\dots&a_1^{n-1}\\
1&a_2&a_2^2&\dots&a_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
1&a_n&a_n^2&\dots&a_n^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}

What is the name of this matrix?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Nicely done @saulspatz !